# bash command starts new process

Tags: command-line, bash, 14.10

I have noticed that whenever I just execute the command `bash` in Terminal that it appears to have executed successfully with no output.

I have also noticed that then when I want to close Terminal I get this:

[image: Process still running]

So by executing the command `bash` I am starting a new process? What does this command by itself do then?

I am running Ubuntu 14.10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`bash` ("Bourne Again Shell") displays the command line and runs whatever you type there.

By default Terminal starts `bash` so it's what you see there if you just open a Terminal.

If you tell `bash` to start another `bash` the new one will by default just look like the old one so it looks like the command has been executed successfully with no output, but it's still running.

You can use the command

```
echo $$
```

to display the process ID (PID) of the currently running `bash` and exit it with

```
exit
```

or <kbd>Ctrl+d</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

When  you execute bash, bash itself is a process and so the terminal warns you that closing the session will kill that process. Even if that process isn't doing anything, it's still running.

If you execute exit it will end that bash session and the terminal won't warn you again.